# VIM filetype plugin does not take expandtab option

Tags: vim

Here's my `.vimrc` what I expect is `expandtab` to work on every mentioned
filetype, except `make` where it is explicitly disabled. `et` used to work as a non-filetype `set` command, but detecting the filetype is important.

```
" vundle Config
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'Shougo/vimproc'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()

filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" Remove whitespace
autocmd BufWritePre * %s/\s\+$//e
autocmd FileType cpp,html,css set et paste tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 backspace=2 matchpairs+=<:>
autocmd FileType haskell,go,js,erlang,vim,tex set et paste tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 backspace=2
autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab paste shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=0
syntax on
```

What I observe is that some options are set, some are not. The expandtab is the one that I can't get to work specifically. Here's the output of `:set` when opening my `.vimrc` file (`filetype=vim`).

```
backspace=2         filetype=vim        keywordprg=:help    paste               shiftwidth=4        tabstop=4           ttymouse=sgr
commentstring="%s   helplang=en         laststatus=2        scroll=21           syntax=vim          ttyfast
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, that's a tricky one. Have a look at [`:help 'paste'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27):

> When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
>
> - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled
> - abbreviations are disabled
> - 'autoindent' is reset
> - **'expandtab' is reset**
> - [...]

Note how the option is introduced:

> This is useful if you want to cut or copy some text from one window and paste it in Vim.

This option only is **meant to be temporarily enabled** when pasting into the terminal. Usually via a key configured in the `'pastetoggle'` option. (GVIM doesn't need it; it can detect pastes. If you have X selection and clipboard enabled, you can also use the `*` and `+` registers instead.)

#### additional comments

- The three `:filetype` commands can be condensed into a single `filetype plugin indent on`.
- If you put this around your `:autocmds`, you'll remove the risk that some plugin clobbers them, and you can also safely *reload* your `~/.vimrc` without defining duplicates:

```
augroup myCustomizations
autocmd!
autocmd ...
augroup END
```

Comment: Very cool (that you knew that reg. `paste` not that `paste` destroys everything). I `set paste` globally before my `au` and that did it. I kind of like having it enabled otherwise I might throw some code and it becomes tabbed to eternity.